# O que significa BCC no email?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, tradução-inglês, português-europeu, abreviações

O que significa BCC no e-mail?

No email tenho essa opção para configurar.

Em que situações devo faze-lo?

Comment: Não é uma sigla portuguesa é inglesa: *Blind Carbon Copy* e quer dizer que é enviada uma cópia do email sem conhecimento dos destinatários. Acho que a pergunta está um bocado fora do âmbito do site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like about internet in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BCC = Blind Carbon Copy = Com Cópia Oculta. É um recurso utilizado quando você quer enviar cópía de uma mensagem para terceiros, porém de modo oculto.  O destinatário principal não saberá que você está endereçando cópia (ou cópias) para terceiros.

Comment: É o equivalente a utilizar CCO !?

Comment: @ClMend    Sim.  (com cópia oculta)